# Error with scene layers when restart the game

Tags: android, andengine

I have two sprites here easyEnemy & bullDozer. easyEnemy spawning in every seconds.So I use time Handler for that .A bulldozer comes in a random time only once.

**Edited:**

**I use generic pool to reuse the easyEnemy. When restart I sending them to pool for reuse. For the bulldozer  I use the normal procedure.**

I want to show the bulldozer above all easyEnemy. I create two layers for that. Like:
Inside GameScene:

```
final int FIRST_LAYER = 0;
final int SECOND_LAYER = 1;

// i call this very first entities in scene
public void createLayers() {


                attachChild(new Entity()); // First Layer
                attachChild(new Entity()); // Second Layer
        }
```

I call createLayers() very first entities in the scene & obviously only once. I attach both easyEnemy And bulldozer in the scene like:

```
// it is called in every seconds inside  time handler
        getChildByIndex(FIRST_LAYER).attachChild(aEasyEnemy);

// it is called only once
        getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(aBulldozer);
```

It works fine for the first time. Bulldozer moves above the easyEnemy. :)

**Problem**:

When I restart the game, Only bulldozer comes with scaling first.But I am not scaled bullDozer. Easy enemy comes after the bulldozer passed from the scene. And the camera hight and width also shortening inside the device. The behaviour is not same like the first run.What I do in restart? The code is below.

**Updated:**

```
    public void onGameRestart() {

                if (hasChildScene()) {

                        clearChildScene();
                        detachChildren();
                        clearTouchAreas();
                        clearEntityModifiers();
                        clearUpdateHandlers();

                        reset();
                        back();
    // sorry I recycle easy Enemy by using pool
    recycleEasyEnemy();

    //  create layers again
    createLayers();

    // call to come again 
    createEasyEnemy(.6f, 28f, 28f);
    createBullDozer();

                 }
        }
```

**Update:** Here is recycleEasyEnemy code:

```
public void recycleEasyEnemy() {
    // send them to pool for reuse

    for (EasyEnemy e : easyEnemyLinkedList) {
        EasyEnemyPool.getSharedEasyEnemyPool().recyclePoolItem(e);
    }
    easyEnemyLinkedList.clear();
}
```

Sorry for not showing my recycleEasyEnemy code before. After running this version, only one problem remains, that is Easy Enemy comes after the bulldozer passing the scene on restart.

**NB:** when I am not calling recycleEasyEnemy it works fine as like the first run. But I have to reuse easyEnemy! on Every restart! Isn't it?

**Solved**: getting new camera height/width problem solved.

**I am almost done it . I need an expert eyes on this code. For simplicity of the post,I just avoid common code block.
Thanks. ;)**

post is also [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/problem-with-scene-layers-when-restart-t11838.html):

Comment: seems some problem with your game restarting way....do this reset(),back() will do all necessary steps...

Comment: well, I remove reset & back from the scene. But got nothing.

Comment: Its better to call these methods clearTouchAreas(); clearEntityModifiers(); clearUpdateHandlers(); Before you clear the sprites/child, Not going to solve the issue but its a better way

Comment: ok..If you have a new idea can share.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call detachSelf() while recycling, or you can also set the parent to null, it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: yes..right you are. detachSelf() is working here. Not, parent to null.

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion, when you clear scene using onGameRestart() method at the same time your two layers also get detached from the scene.

So for next time when your createEasyEnemy() and createBullDozer() methods add their data on **0** and **1** index element. So this time your 0 and 1 index element is another entity rather than **Entity**. So you have to first attach your entity to get all the thing as normal as your first run.

Only because of this your first run was perfect and next time gets problem.

Comment: hello @Siddharth thanks for share.That means I have to attach again my createLayers() in onGamerestart() before calling createEasyEnemy() &  createBullDozer()?I give u feedback tomorrow. please stay close.

Comment: Because in your code you already detachChildren() called. So your both entities are children of your scene. So they get removed from the scene.

Comment: I reply you after test this. I Follow you both andengine Forums & game stack exchange. People need some expert eyes on their code when andengine have lag of docs. Hope Your contribution should be continued.

Comment: I find the solution. Means when I recycle the easyEnemy I have to detachSelf it the from the old entity layer. Otherwise problem arises when attach them again to a new layer.

Answer (score 0):

From your onGameRestart() method remove the detachChildren();

Comment: I must use detachChildren() to clear the entity from the scene on restart.so I searched something different.@FIROJ